# Facebook Data Science Question (Expected Payout and Probability)

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian

I saw this question on Glassdoor and couldn't seem to find a answer to validate mine anywhere:

> You're at a casino with two dice, if you roll a 5 you win, and get paid $10. 
>   What is your expected payout? If you play until you win (however long that 
>   takes) then stop, what is your expected payout?

I interpret this as "if at least one of the dice gives you a 5", so expected payout for one roll:

> $(1 - (\frac{5}{6})^2) \times 10$

But I am kind of confused on calculating expected payout until you win. Is it:

> $(1 - (\frac{5}{6})^2)^n \times 10$

where you have to indicate the number of rolls? Or is there another way?

I am fairly new to this so I really appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Does each roll cost something?  If not...then isn't the answer obviously $\$10$?

Comment: Totally agree with @lulu...as it stands, it reads like one of those "don't over-think it" questions.

Comment: Oh so this is one of those expected value question, basically if you get 5 you win 10 but if you didn't get 5 you don't get anything. So essentially this type of question is asking for the "average payout" (not sure if I am describing this correctly...)

Comment: You got the expected payout for one roll right. The comments above refer to the second part of the question. Since you didn't specify any cost, the answer to this part is trivial: If you play until you win, the expected payout is $10$. The question would only be interesting if there's some further component, such as a cost per roll.

Comment: I believe the usual interpretation of 'rolling a 5' is that the _total_ on the two dice is 5. So on any one roll of two dice that's a probability of 4/36 = 1/9.

Answer (score 1):

Any interview questions are not like Captcha, they require your engagement in dialog rather than just being a computer. So, for me really two options here and choice is up to interviewer ( i.e. you supposed to ask clarifying questions, this tests your communicative ability ).

First option is when they mean total of 5 when adding 2 dice together.  If so, the probability of a win is 4 / 36 = 1 / 9. Expected payout of 1 toss is $10 / 9.

Expected payout of paying until you win is $10 = $10/9 x (1 - 8/9)^-1. 8/9 being a probability of not winning.

Another option is if it is win $10 if either dice is a 5. Then
first, let's compute the  probability of winning. 
I think it is  1/6 (5 on the 1st dice) + 5/6 (not a 5 on 1st dice) x 1/6 (5 on 2nd dice) = 6/36 + 5/36 = 11/36

Then 
E[Payout 1 toss] = $10 * 11/36 = 110/36

E[Payout pay until win] = 110/36 * (1 + 25/36 + (25/36)^2 ... ) = 110/36 * (1 - 25/36)^-1 = 110/36*(11/36)^-1 = $10

And if I was at that interview I would present both solutions and then ask clarifying questions.